# iOs Image Recognition, Categorizing and matching pattern

Tags: ios, swift, image-recognition

I have been investigation a little about image recognition, But Haven't found something useful for me yet.
For my Wife who Is a Dentist that has to make his Tesis, I need to make an App that recognize all teeth Shape from a picture taken at standard conditions.
I need to find the best match based on teeth pattern predefined to categorize and see which match best. I know this is a big issue and not a simple solution.
Does someone know an image recognition software that makes me able to give it a a number of patterns, and then have an image and see wich pattern fits the best? Or maybe just some orientation to start searching and working on solving this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenCV would be the way to go here but let me give you the facts before you start ripping your hair out.

I don't know your development experience but although OpenCV has an iOS wrapper you **will be working with low-level, C libraries**. If that makes you uncomfortable then turn back now. Furthermore, you will be writing the majority of the recognition/detection algorithms yourself and it takes a lot of time and patience to get these to the point where they work to an extent. Additionally, don't expect the end product to be all that reliable, professional image recognition/manipulation tools take **years** of development by teams of experts in computer vision. No disrespect but something that has been hacked together over a few weeks by one person will be sub-par and lacking.

Nonetheless if you want to go ahead, you can download OpenCV for iOS here:
http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html